How to Draw a circle of 3 km radius in ASPMAP lib for vb.net?
Using below code to trying ring/circle on map Using ASPMAP lib in VB.Net
  Dim aTmp(), cName As String
  Dim oAspMapLayer As Layer
  Dim oDynLayer As DynamicLayer
  Dim i, iLayerIndex, iNewLayerIndex, iMaxLayerIndex As Integer
  Dim oCoordSys As New CoordSystem(AspMap.CoordSystemCode.GCS_WGS84)
  Dim oRecordset As AspMap.Recordset
  oDynLayer = New AspMap.DynamicLayer()

  oAspMapLayer = m_MapSrv(NP_REG_LAYER)
  oRecordset = oAspMapLayer.Recordset

  Dim oShape As New AspMap.Shape
  'oShape = JoinShapes(oAspMapLayer.Recordset, "shape")
  Dim x As Double = CLng(cData.Split(";")(0))
  Dim y As Double = CLng(cData.Split(";")(1))

  Dim radius As Double = distance
  oShape.MakeCircle(x, y, radius)
  oDynLayer.Add(oShape, cIsoType)


  iMaxLayerIndex = -1
  If (cLayerName = "") Then
      For i = 0 To m_MapSrv.LayerCount - 1
          cName = m_MapSrv.Layer(i).Name
          If (InStr(cName, NP_ISO_PFX) = 1) Then
              aTmp = cName.Split("_")
              Integer.TryParse(aTmp(2), iLayerIndex)
              If (iLayerIndex > iMaxLayerIndex) Then
                  iMaxLayerIndex = iLayerIndex
              End If
          End If
      Next
      cLayerName = NP_ISO_PFX & (iMaxLayerIndex + 1)
  End If
  iLayerIndex = m_MapSrv.GetLayerIndex(cLayerName)
  If (iLayerIndex >= 0) Then
      m_MapSrv.RemoveLayer(cLayerName)
  End If
  oAspMapLayer = m_MapSrv.AddLayer(oDynLayer)
  oAspMapLayer.Name = cLayerName
  oAspMapLayer.CoordinateSystem = New CoordSystem(AspMap.CoordSystemCode.GCS_WGS84)
  iNewLayerIndex = m_MapSrv.GetLayerIndex(cLayerName)
  If (iLayerIndex >= 0) Then
      m_MapSrv.MoveLayer(iNewLayerIndex, iLayerIndex)
  Else
      Dim oLayer As New MapLayer With {
          .Name = cLayerName,
          .Pen = cPen,
          .Brush = cBrush,
          .Symbol = cSymbol,
          .LayGroupType = LAYER_GROUP_TYPE.GR_GRE,
          .Visible = True,
          .InfoToolSelectable = False,
          .LabelToolSelectable = False,
          .UseCustomStyle = False}
      m_Layers.Add(oLayer)
  End If

using  oShape.MakeCircle(x, y, radius) function its give ellipse instead of circle.

What is your question? (please edit)

I am using ASPMAP lib to generate map using sharp file. I want to draw circle/ring on map giving radius and coordinates.

Please add that information to your question, rather than in a comment. And can you also explain what is not working now?

using oShape.MakeCircle(x, y, radius) function its give elips instead of circle.

Circles aren't circles in most map projections, and especially not in Plate Carrée of a geographic coordinate system. If you do get a circle, it's probably wrong.

is there other way to create circle, using old ASPMAP lib and Projection is  Dim oCoordSys As New CoordSystem(AspMap.CoordSystemCode.GCS_WGS84)
